# how to print two value in ada

Tags: ada

How to print two value in ada below is my code lets say there is two file one ads (specification)i.e try.ads and other main file i.e main.adb

try.ads

```
  package try is
    type My_limit  is range 0..31;
    package Useme is new ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO(My_limit);
  end try;
```

main.adb

```
  with try
  procedure main is
  demo:try.rt_adrr:=3;
 begin
   try.Useme.put("hello" & try.rt_addr); -- error is Missing arguement for parameter "item" call to "put" 
  end main;
```

I know the error is because of "try.useme.put" because "hello" string is not  define in  the "Useme" package so please help me i want to print this both in single statment  hello and 3?

Comment: It’s difficult to help you because the code you have posted could hardly begin to compile, there are so many errors in it. We need **code that we can compile** or at least try to.

Comment: The code in your question does not produce that error message. Please update your question; copy-and-paste the *exact* code that you're feeding to the compiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are other errors (I have no idea what either `try.rt_addr` or `try.rt_adrr` is, and Ada is not forgiving about spelling the same name different ways).

However, to answer what I think is the main question: You can't concatenate a string and an integer (or any other numeric type) the way some languages allow.  Thus, if `rt_addr` is an integer, this expression is not legal anywhere:

```
"hello" & rt_addr
```

unless you've defined your own `"&"` that takes a `String` parameter and an `Integer` parameter and (probably) returns a `String`.  I've seen this done, but I don't believe it's the usual way to accomplish this.

The normal way to output both, assuming you have a package like your `Useme` to output integers, is to use more than one `put`

```
Ada.Text_IO.Put("Hello");
Try.Useme.Put(rt_addr);
```

Comment: I’d usually do `”hello” & Integer’Image (Rt_Addr)` or the GNAT-ism `”hello” & Rt_Addr’Img` - unless I couldn’t accept the default formatting.

Comment: @SimonWright Right, using `Put` gives you more formatting options.